# Parsing the file in Python

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x

I have file in the following format:

```
Berlin, Germany 
New Delhi , India
New York , USA 
Mumbai , India
Seattle, USA
```

I need to parse the file and print the output as

```
Germany : Berlin
India: New Delhi , Mumbai 
USA:  New York, Seattle
```

I wrote a code:

```
enter code here:

def check():
    datafile=open('logfile.py','rU')
    found=False
    for line in datafile:
        if 'India' in line:
           lines=line.split()
           print("India"+":"+lines[0])
        if 'Germany' in line:
           lines=line.split()
           print("Germany"+":"+lines[0])
        if 'USA' in line:
           lines=line.split()
           print("USA"+":"+lines[0])
    datafile.close()
check()
```

This code is giving output as:

```
Germany:Berlin
India:NewDelhi
USA:NewYork
India:Mumbai
USA:Seattle
```

Please help.

Comment: How are you doing a default `split()` and losing the commas?

Comment: Essentially, as you can see in the first answer, you'll have to make lists for all countries. So the trick is to start a country list, then decide whether a country already exists or not, then append the city to the country list.

Comment: @roadrunner66 - `collections.defaultdict` manages all of that for you

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Ty :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach, is using `defaultdict` from `collections` to achieve this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def check():
    d = defaultdict(list)
    with open('logfile.py', 'rU') as datafile:
        for line in datafile:
            data = line.split(',')
            d[data[1].strip()].append(data[0].strip())
    return d
res = check()

for k, v in res.items():
    print("{} : {}".format(k, ', '.join(v)))
```

Output:

```
India : New Delhi, Mumbai
Germany : Berlin
USA : New York, Seattle
```

Comment: Nice – now it makes me wonder how to get that irrational spacing in the original 'required' list.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of directly printing everything, you could save it to a data structure like a dictionary or `collections.defaultdict`.

```
import collections.defaultdict as dd
result = dd(list)
with open('logfile.py', 'rU') as datafile:
    for line in datafile:
        city,country = map(str.strip, line.strip().split(','))
        result[country].append(city)
```

Then print your results:

```
for country in result:
    print(country+':', ', '.join(result[country]))
```

If you think there may be duplicate country/city listings and you don't want them, use `set` and `add` instead of `list` and `append`.